Pandas Split By First Delimiter and Add Excess to Different Column
I have a column in my dataframe for email addresses. Sometimes the field contains multiple emails separated by ; 
EMAIL                                                      COMMENT
email1@example.com                                         Example Comment
email2@example.com; email3@example.com
email4@example.com; email5@example.com; e6@ex.com          Another comment

My goal is to have the EMAIL field only have 1 email and append all the extra emails to the COMMENT column. Here is my ideal output:
EMAIL                      COMMENT
email1@example.com        Example Comment
email2@example.com        Emails=email3@example.com
email4@example.com        Another comment|Emails=email5@example.com; e6@ex.com

Here is my code thus far:
df['EMAIL2'] = df['EMAIL'].str.split('; ', 1).str[0] # Split on `; ` if exist and only keep first email
df['COMMENT'] += "|Emails=" + df['EMAIL'].str.split('; ', 1).str[1]
df['EMAIL'] = df['EMAIL2'] # Set Email = Email2


You could use:
import numpy as np

# split once as dataframe
tmp = (df['EMAIL'].str.split(r';\s*', n=1, expand=True)
       # safety in case there is only one email
       .reindex(columns=[0, 1])
      )

# update email with first part of split
df['EMAIL'] = tmp[0]

# identify rows to update
# add Emails= or |Emails= depending on context 
# add second part of split
df.loc[tmp[1].notna(), 'COMMENT'] = (
    df['COMMENT'].fillna('')
    +np.where(df['COMMENT'].isna(),
             'Emails=', '|Emails=')
    +tmp[1]
  )

Variant, as suggested by @Nick:
tmp = df['EMAIL'].str.extract('([^;]+);?\s*(.*)', expand=True)

df['EMAIL'] = tmp[0]

df.loc[tmp[1].ne(''), 'COMMENT'] = (
    df['COMMENT'].fillna('')
    +np.where(df['COMMENT'].isna(),
             'Emails=', '|Emails=')
    +tmp[1]
  )

Output:
                EMAIL                                               COMMENT
0  email1@example.com                                       Example Comment
1  email2@example.com                             Emails=email3@example.com
2  email4@example.com  Another comment|Emails=email5@example.com; e6@ex.com


Using df['EMAIL'].str.extract('([^;]+);?\s*(.*)', expand=True) would save the need for the reindex

Try:
df["COMMENT"] = (
    df["COMMENT"]
    + df.apply(
        lambda row: (
            f"|Emails={s}" if (s := row["EMAIL"].split("; ", maxsplit=1)[-1]) else ""
        ),
        axis=1,
    )
).str.strip("|")

df["EMAIL"] = df["EMAIL"].str.split("; ").str[0]

print(df)

Prints:
                EMAIL                                               COMMENT
0  email1@example.com             Example Comment|Emails=email1@example.com
1  email2@example.com                             Emails=email3@example.com
2  email4@example.com  Another comment|Emails=email5@example.com; e6@ex.com

